# CakePHP 1.3 - Infinite looping in cake libraries, Apache crash, Session helper and __start()?

Tags: php, apache, session, cakephp, infinite-loop

Upon adding the session helper to the app controller Apache begins crashing. I've tracked the problem down a ways with logging and found that in /CORE/cake/libs/controller/component/session the function `check()` starts running once and doesn't complete. However, the function it calls ,`__start()`, runs infinitely (at least until Apache crashes it). And by running infinitely I mean the entire `__start()` function is run multiple times all the way through. Again, this happens once I add the session helper in app controller. Without it Cake seems to run fine until I hit a point where the session helper is used in a view. This system is being upgraded from Cake 1.1 and in Cake 1.1 the session helper was automatically included and ran fine. I've attempted this on both Cake 1.3.7 and Cake 1.3.15 with the same result. I'm guessing something with the session settings conflicts with the way Cake 1.3 does things. Below is my config/core file, the crash information from Apache, and the Apache log just before the crash. If any other information would be helpful please let me know in the comments. Any suggestions how to fix this? Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to include a relevant [discussion here](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1173-cakesession-circular-dependancy-race-condition-or-infinite-loop). Unfortunately, they don't have a clear solution here, but they appear to want to fix the bug in cake, where I would be happy to alter my code to avoid the bug.

EDIT 2: I recently discovered that the manager of this project plans to discontinue the use of database sessions in the future, so that completely fixes the situation for me. Of course I will leave this question up for future visitors though.

app/config/core.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * This is core configuration file.
 *
 * Use it to configure core behavior of Cake.
 *
 * PHP versions 4 and 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2010, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2010, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       cake
 * @subpackage    cake.app.config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */

/**
 * CakePHP Debug Level:
 *
 * Production Mode:
 *  0: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown. Flash messages redirect.
 *
 * Development Mode:
 *  1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.
 *  2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.
 *
 * In production mode, flash messages redirect after a time interval.
 * In development mode, you need to click the flash message to continue.
 */
    //Configure::write('debug', 2);

/**
 * CakePHP Log Level:
 *
 * In case of Production Mode CakePHP gives you the possibility to continue logging errors.
 *
 * The following parameters can be used:
 *  Boolean: Set true/false to activate/deactivate logging
 *    Configure::write('log', true);
 *
 *  Integer: Use built-in PHP constants to set the error level (see error_reporting)
 *    Configure::write('log', E_ERROR | E_WARNING);
 *    Configure::write('log', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 */
    //Configure::write('log', true);

/**
 * Application wide charset encoding
 */
    //Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');

/**
 * To configure CakePHP *not* to use mod_rewrite and to
 * use CakePHP pretty URLs, remove these .htaccess
 * files:
 *
 * /.htaccess
 * /app/.htaccess
 * /app/webroot/.htaccess
 *
 * And uncomment the App.baseUrl below:
 */
    //Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));

/**
 * Uncomment the define below to use CakePHP prefix routes.
 *
 * The value of the define determines the names of the routes
 * and their associated controller actions:
 *
 * Set to an array of prefixes you want to use in your application. Use for
 * admin or other prefixed routes.
 *
 *  Routing.prefixes = array('admin', 'manager');
 *
 * Enables:
 *  `admin_index()` and `/admin/controller/index`
 *  `manager_index()` and `/manager/controller/index`
 *
 * [Note Routing.admin is deprecated in 1.3.  Use Routing.prefixes instead]
 */
    //Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));

/**
 * Turn off all caching application-wide.
 *
 */
    //Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);

    define('DEBUG', 2);
    define('DEBUG_AJAX', true);
/**
 * Enable cache checking.
 *
 * If set to true, for view caching you must still use the controller
 * var $cacheAction inside your controllers to define caching settings.
 * You can either set it controller-wide by setting var $cacheAction = true,
 * or in each action using $this->cacheAction = true.
 *
 */
    Configure::write('Cache.check', false);

/**
 * Defines the default error type when using the log() function. Used for
 * differentiating error logging and debugging. Currently PHP supports LOG_DEBUG.
 */
    define('LOG_ERROR', 2);

/**
 * The preferred session handling method. Valid values:
 *
 * 'php'            Uses settings defined in your php.ini.
 * 'cake'       Saves session files in CakePHP's /tmp directory.
 * 'database'   Uses CakePHP's database sessions.
 *
 * To define a custom session handler, save it at /app/config/<name>.php.
 * Set the value of 'Session.save' to <name> to utilize it in CakePHP.
 *
 * To use database sessions, run the app/config/schema/sessions.php schema using
 * the cake shell command: cake schema create Sessions
 *
 */
    Configure::write('Session.save', 'database');

/**
 * The model name to be used for the session model.
 *
 * 'Session.save' must be set to 'database' in order to utilize this constant.
 *
 * The model name set here should *not* be used elsewhere in your application.
 */
    Configure::write('Session.model', 'Session');

/**
 * The name of the table used to store CakePHP database sessions.
 *
 * 'Session.save' must be set to 'database' in order to utilize this constant.
 *
 * The table name set here should *not* include any table prefix defined elsewhere.
 *
 * Please note that if you set a value for Session.model (above), any value set for
 * Session.table will be ignored.
 *
 * [Note: Session.table is deprecated as of CakePHP 1.3]
 */
    Configure::write('Session.table', 'cake_sessions');

/**
 * The DATABASE_CONFIG::$var to use for database session handling.
 *
 * 'Session.save' must be set to 'database' in order to utilize this constant.
 */
    Configure::write('Session.database', 'default');

/**
 * The name of CakePHP's session cookie.
 *
 * Note the guidelines for Session names states: "The session name references
 * the session id in cookies and URLs. It should contain only alphanumeric
 * characters."
 * @link http://php.net/session_name
 */
    Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'CAKEPHP');

/**
 * Session time out time (in seconds).
 * Actual value depends on 'Security.level' setting.
 */
    Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');

/**
 * If set to false, sessions are not automatically started.
 */
    Configure::write('Session.start', true);

/**
 * When set to false, HTTP_USER_AGENT will not be checked
 * in the session. You might want to set the value to false, when dealing with
 * older versions of IE, Chrome Frame or certain web-browsing devices and AJAX
 */
    Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', true);

/**
 * The level of CakePHP security. The session timeout time defined
 * in 'Session.timeout' is multiplied according to the settings here.
 * Valid values:
 *
 * 'high'   Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 10
 * 'medium' Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 100
 * 'low'    Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 300
 *
 * CakePHP session IDs are also regenerated between requests if
 * 'Security.level' is set to 'high'.
 */
    Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');

/**
 * A random string used in security hashing methods.
 */
    Configure::write('Security.salt', 'DYhG93b0qyJfIxfs2guVoUubWwvniR2G0FgaC9mi');

/**
 * A random numeric string (digits only) used to encrypt/decrypt strings.
 */
    Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', '76859309657453542496749683645');

/**
 * Apply timestamps with the last modified time to static assets (js, css, images).
 * Will append a querystring parameter containing the time the file was modified. This is
 * useful for invalidating browser caches.
 *
 * Set to `true` to apply timestamps, when debug = 0, or set to 'force' to always enable
 * timestamping.
 */
    //Configure::write('Asset.timestamp', true);
/**
 * Compress CSS output by removing comments, whitespace, repeating tags, etc.
 * This requires a/var/cache directory to be writable by the web server for caching.
 * and /vendors/csspp/csspp.php
 *
 * To use, prefix the CSS link URL with '/ccss/' instead of '/css/' or use HtmlHelper::css().
 */
    //Configure::write('Asset.filter.css', 'css.php');

/**
 * Plug in your own custom JavaScript compressor by dropping a script in your webroot to handle the
 * output, and setting the config below to the name of the script.
 *
 * To use, prefix your JavaScript link URLs with '/cjs/' instead of '/js/' or use JavaScriptHelper::link().
 */
    //Configure::write('Asset.filter.js', 'custom_javascript_output_filter.php');

/**
 * The classname and database used in CakePHP's
 * access control lists.
 */
    Configure::write('Acl.classname', 'DbAcl');
    Configure::write('Acl.database', 'default');

/**
 * If you are on PHP 5.3 uncomment this line and correct your server timezone
 * to fix the date & time related errors.
 */
    //date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

/**
 *
 * Cache Engine Configuration
 * Default settings provided below
 *
 * File storage engine.
 *
 *   Cache::config('default', array(
 *      'engine' => 'File', //[required]
 *      'duration'=> 3600, //[optional]
 *      'probability'=> 100, //[optional]
 *      'path' => CACHE, //[optional] use system tmp directory - remember to use absolute path
 *      'prefix' => 'cake_', //[optional]  prefix every cache file with this string
 *      'lock' => false, //[optional]  use file locking
 *      'serialize' => true, [optional]
 *  ));
 *
 *
 * APC (http://pecl.php.net/package/APC)
 *
 *   Cache::config('default', array(
 *      'engine' => 'Apc', //[required]
 *      'duration'=> 3600, //[optional]
 *      'probability'=> 100, //[optional]
 *      'prefix' => Inflector::slug(APP_DIR) . '_', //[optional]  prefix every cache file with this string
 *  ));
 *
 * Xcache (http://xcache.lighttpd.net/)
 *
 *   Cache::config('default', array(
 *      'engine' => 'Xcache', //[required]
 *      'duration'=> 3600, //[optional]
 *      'probability'=> 100, //[optional]
 *      'prefix' => Inflector::slug(APP_DIR) . '_', //[optional] prefix every cache file with this string
 *      'user' => 'user', //user from xcache.admin.user settings
 *      'password' => 'password', //plaintext password (xcache.admin.pass)
 *  ));
 *
 *
 * Memcache (http://www.danga.com/memcached/)
 *
 *   Cache::config('default', array(
 *      'engine' => 'Memcache', //[required]
 *      'duration'=> 3600, //[optional]
 *      'probability'=> 100, //[optional]
 *      'prefix' => Inflector::slug(APP_DIR) . '_', //[optional]  prefix every cache file with this string
 *      'servers' => array(
 *          '127.0.0.1:11211' // localhost, default port 11211
 *      ), //[optional]
 *      'compress' => false, // [optional] compress data in Memcache (slower, but uses less memory)
 *  ));
 *
 */
    Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));

/**
 * This is the URL at which your working copy
 * is accessed -- no trailing forward slash
 */
        define('BIRT_REPORT_BASE_URL', '');

/**
 * This is the directory to which BIRT has
 * permission to write files during graphing
 */
        define('BIRT_REPORT_WRITABLE_IMAGE_DIR', '');
```

Apache crash:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.2.11.0
  Application Timestamp:    493f5d44
  Fault Module Name:    php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.2.9.9
  Fault Module Timestamp:   49a56925
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 001a049d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 8278
  Additional Information 2: 82782538381a8681201b9137311ac754
  Additional Information 3: 9f8d
  Additional Information 4: 9f8d09670f894d997bbbca5236befa87
```

Apache error.log:

```
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:01 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i PHP/5.2.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:01 2013] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:01 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 7024
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:02 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:02 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:03 2013] [notice] Child 7024: Child process is running
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:03 2013] [notice] Child 7024: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:03 2013] [notice] Child 7024: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:03 2013] [notice] Child 7024: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Fri Apr 19 10:52:03 2013] [notice] Child 7024: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Comment: I've upvoted for the effort. Is it possible to upgrade to cake 2.x?

Comment: We're hoping to that eventually. But we'd like to get to cake 1.3 first so we can use the well documented transition methods from 1.3 to 2.x. It's actually a fairly large (and old system) so that transition might take a while and if we can get to 1.3 quickly first it would help with many issues we have now because it will allow us to use a newer version of PHP quickly. So upgrading to 2.x is a good choice, but we'd like the quicker route of 1.3 for the time being if possible.

Comment: Can you try changing the sessions to not use the database? http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Sessions.html

Comment: @systematical: Thanks for the comment. This does allow it to work, but we would like to use database sessions.

Comment: Understood, this just helps isolate the problem further. Are you sure you have the proper schema for your sessions table? I'd start looking in that direction.

Comment: @systematical: I'm pretty sure. As you might have noticed I posted a answer that is a workaround. With this workaround the Sessions work as expected. With that It would seem that there's nothing wrong with the schema I would think. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that allows the database version of sessions to work. It is not a fix, but it will probably work for my situation, although the real fix would still be preferred.

The work around is to turn the agent check off:

```
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
```

Comment: Can you share your session table schema?  Does it have a column to store the user agent?

Comment: @AdamBrett: No, the only columns in the cake_sessions table is id (VARCHAR), data (TEXT), and expires (INT)